# How to reference a C# delegate from within its code block?

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm developing a program that makes heavy use of delegates. For simplicity, let's assume I have the following class:

```
class ProcContainer<T>
{
    public delegate T Proc(ProcContainer<T> parentContainer); // my delegate type

    public Proc Content; // a field in the class in which a Proc "instance" is stored
}
```

To put it into words: `Proc` is a delegate type that accepts a `ProcContainer` as its (only) argument. And a `ProcContainer` contains a `Proc` "instance" in its `Content` field.

Now I want to create a delegate like this:

```
T someVal = new T();

ProcContainer<T>.Proc proc = delegate(ProcContainer<T> parentContainer)
{
    parentContainer.Content = <<<this_delegate>>>;
    return someVal;
};
```

Again, to put it into words: I'd like to create a `Proc` instance accepting a `ProcContainer` that sets the content of the `ProcContainer` to the `Proc` at hand.

Therefore, if my `Proc` is invoked, it should overwrite the current content of the provided `ProcContainer` with itself.

Questions: Can I do that in C#? If yes: How?

Comment: declare `ProcContainer<T>.Proc proc = null`; before assigning it the real code... `ProcContainer<T>.Proc proc = null; proc = delegate(......)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<<<this_delegate>>>` is equal to `proc` but you have to tweak the code a bit to get it to compile (and to work logically).

```
ProcContainer<T>.Proc proc = null;
proc = delegate(ProcContainer<T> parentContainer)
{
    parentContainer.Content = proc;
    return someVal;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, I wanted to try exactly that but finally I did not because I though that `null` would be enclosed in the hidden delegate helper class instead of the actual `Proc` instance. Should have tried it nevertheless. Heh.

Answer (score 1):

I note that you have a solution but not an explanation for why the original code produces an error. It is tricky to concisely make an anonymous function which calls itself.

If the variable that contains the delegate instance is local then an attempt to use the local in its own initialization is typically flagged as an attempt to read a local variable before it is known to be written.

If the variable that contains the delegate instance is an instance field then an attempt to use the field in its own initialization is typically flagged as a use of `this` in a field initializer, which is illegal. (It is illegal because that is a common cause of bugs; the `this` in a field initializer refers to an object whose constructor has not yet run, which can cause all kinds of bugs were you to dereference it.)

Now, you might reasonably note that in the first case the variable is typically merely "mentioned" and not actually "read". And in the second case the "this" is again not dereferenced. Rather than create a special rule that softens the general rules should the violation appear in an uninvoked anonymous function, the language design team decided to simply make the rules apply generally. Though this is a bit of an annoyance, there is no special case that needs to be designed, specified, implemented, tested, and then explained in the documentation.

I noted that it is not *easy* to make an anonymous function that calls itself without doing the assignment to the variable in a separate step. It is not *impossible*. You can do so by making clever use of the Y combinator for anonymous recursion. But doing so makes the code sufficiently hard to read that most people would not consider it to be a good solution.